# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ... (wrong name: ....)

Tags: java, runtime-error, noclassdeffounderror

I know there are already several posts about this but I couldn't make any sense of them.

I have build a custom DateSpinner with a MVC pattern:

```
package my.app.myDateSpinner  // public class MyDateSpinner
package my.app.myDateSpinner.controller // public class MyDateSpinnerController
package my.app.myDateSpinner.model // public class MyDateSpinnerModel
package my.app.myDateSpinner.view // public class MyDateSpinnerView
```

The code is located in:

```
c:\My Code\src\my\app\myDateSpinner
```

I'm using Dr.Java and I have added to the classpath:

```
C:\My Code\src
```

Now I am trying to use it on another project. In order to do that I use:

```
import my.app.myDateSpinner.*;
```

It compiles without any problem but I get the following error during runtime:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my/app/myDateSpinner/view/MyDateSpinnerView (wrong name: MyDateSpinnerView)
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error from MyDateSpinnerView and not from MyDateSpinnerModel or MyDateSpinnerController and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: The java command needs to include the full package name of the class.

Comment: There is no `package` statement in MyDateSpinnerView.java.

Comment: @NormR What java command?

Comment: @user207421 Yes, there is. `package my.app.myDateSpinner.view`

Comment: The JVM doesn't agree with you,. Look at what it printed for the name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the problem. It was the IDE (Dr. Java).

I am not sure what happend but today when I opened it, it crashed. Then, I opened it again and all the settings were set to default. I had to set all the preferences again and everything worked just fine.